# How does one prove that a prime $p$ does not generate the multiplicative group of integers mod $4p-1$?

Tags: group-theory, modular-arithmetic

Another way to word the question:

If the multiplicative group is called $U_{4p-1}$, then how does one prove that $U_{4p-1}/<p>$ contains more than one element?

I'm having trouble approaching this problem, because I don't see a way to use the $4$ in $4p-1$. I've tried considering $p^k$ (mod $4$), but it doesn't get me anywhere. I've also realized that if $4p-1$ is prime, then the order of the multiplicative group is $2$ in mod $4$, but I don't know what to do with that information.

Any help or hints would be appreciated.

Comment: It isnt always odd.

Comment: for example the order of $13\bmod 51$ is $4$.

Comment: for $p \leq 29,$ it turns out that $p$ is a square modulo every prime factor of $4p-1,$ therefore by CRT $p$ is a square. Which, if always true, would do the job

Comment: Thanks Jorge, I fixed that.

Comment: We don't need $p$ to be a prime though.

Comment: **Hint** $\,\ {\rm mod}\ 4p\!-\!1\!:\,\ p\equiv 1/4\equiv (1/2)^2\ \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick a prime divisor $q$ of $4p-1$.

Notice that $4p\equiv 1 \bmod q$, since both $4$ and $1$ are quadratic residues $\bmod q$ we conclude that $p$ is a quadratic residue $\bmod q$.

So in particular we can never have $p^k\equiv -1 \bmod q$ and as a consequence we can't have $p^k \equiv -1 \bmod 4p-1$ either.

Comment: There's the answer. Thank you.

Comment: happy to help.${}$